# how can i translate the ethers.js "getSigner" utility to web3?

Tags: web3js, contract-design, web3-providers, ethers.js

I have a web3 object but I'm working off an example that uses `ethersProvider.getSigner()`. Is there an equivalent (or mostly equivalent) in the web3 library?

For reference, the ethersProvider is instantiated with `const ethersProvider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.web3.currentProvider);`

and the signer is `ethersProvider.getSigner()`

Answer (score 1):

web3 works a bit different than ether.js so when you deal with web3 you first establish a connection with the dapp and than when you call a function which change the state you use send() and pass from field with it.

// Do connect to the metamask and bring the account address.

Example:

```
const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
         
const contract = web3.eth.Contract(abi,Contractaddress);          
         
const data = contract.methods.randomFunction.send({from: `${account[0]}`});
```